# Error in a simple gstreamer code to play an "mp3" audio file

Tags: audio, mp3, gstreamer, bus

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GstElement *element;
    GstElement *element1;
    GstElement *element2;
    GstElement *pipeline;

    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    if(argc != 2)
    {
        g_print("usage: %s argv[1] \n", argv[0]);

        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Creating a new pipeline */
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    /* creating a new *.mp3 source element */
    element = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "source");
    if(element != NULL)
        g_object_set(G_OBJECT(element), "location", argv[1], NULL);
    else
    {
        g_print("Failed to create element \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* creating a new *.mp3 de-coder element */
    element1 = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin2", "decoder");
    if(element1 != NULL)
        g_print("element1 success \n");
    else
    {
        g_print("Failed to create element1 \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* creating a new *.mp3 sink element */
    element2 = gst_element_factory_make("autoaudiosink", "play_audio");
    if(element2 != NULL)
        g_print("element2 success \n");
    else
    {
        g_print("Failed to create element2 \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Adding elements to pipeline */
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), element, element1, element2, NULL);

    /* Linking src to sink element */
    gst_element_link_many(element, element1, element2, NULL);

    /* start playing */
    gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline), GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    while(gst_bin_iterate_recurse(GST_BIN(pipeline)));

    /* stop playing */
    gst_element_set_state(GST_ELEMENT(pipeline), GST_STATE_NULL);

    /* un-referencing all the elements in the pipeline */
    gst_object_unref(GST_OBJECT(pipeline));

    return 0;
}
```

1) Compilation step:- gcc gst6.c -o gst6 `pk-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-0.10`, 
   it is compiling without any warnings and errors.
2) Exported PKG_CONFIG_PATH env variable i.e. export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lin/pkgconfig. 
3) Execution step: ./gst6 /home/user/Downloads/*.mp3 
4) Output: element1 success, 
           element2 success
           killed.

Unable to play the audio file. Please let me know whats wrong in my program. This is my first program.

Comment: What does "Unable to play the audio file" mean? What part of the code seems to not be working? You've posted dozens of lines of code, with a subject that could be reduced to "gstreamer code to play an MP3 file" and "Unable to play the audio file. Please let me know whats wrong". It's better if **you** tell **us** what's wrong (as in what the problem is), and we can try to help you fix it. :-)

Comment: gstreamer plugins writer guide has complete code to decode mp3 file. also run your program with --gst-debug=*:5 --gst-debug-no-color to get the gst logs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
while(gst_bin_iterate_recurse(GST_BIN(pipeline)));
```

does not make any sense. It [requests an iterator](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBin.html#gst-bin-iterate-recurse) in a loop, but does not use it, neither [frees](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/gstreamer-GstIterator.html#gst-iterator-free) it.

If you want to wait until playing is finished, you probably need to use the [GstBus](http://developer.gnome.org/gstreamer/stable/GstBus.html#GstBus.description) functions `gst_bus_have_pending` and `gst_bus_pop` to handle messages.

Comment: Merry Christmas :).Thanks Wimmel, . I used GstBus function and it's working now.